# How to convert JSON Object to JSON Array in C# Restsharp (Exception- cannot convert newtonsoft.json.linq.jobject to newtonsoft.json.linq.array")

Tags: c#, json, json.net, restsharp

Below is my Requirement-

**Actual JSON=**
{
"page":2,
"per_page":6,
"total":12,
"total_pages":2
}

**I want to make it as below-**

[
{
"page":2,
"per_page":6,
"total":12,
"total_pages":2
}
]

It would be great help if someone can provide the best logic to do this in C# (RestSharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can store your json data inside the list.

```
var json = new
{
   name = "john doe",
   age = 20
};

var list = new List<dynamic>();

list.Add(json);
```

Later on, when you serialize your list. It will look like this:

```
[{"name":"john doe","age":20}]
```

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for your support. Have a great day!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty array and then push json object into that array.

Example :

```
var obj = { "name":"test", "email":"test@test.com" };
var list = [];
list.push(obj);
```

Result :

```
list = [{ "name":"test", "email":"test@test.com" }];
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for the response. When im trying this in my C# class so Im getting syntax error for below code-

var list = [];
list.push(obj);

and there is no push method is available.
Please guide me if I am making any mistake here. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code, this is working one.

```
var obj = new { name = "test", email = "test@test.com" };
var list = new List<dynamic>();
list.Add(obj);
```